# character count using C (discrepancy between cli-tools and my file)

Tags: c, bash

I was testing this function on some sample text file to make sure it is working as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BUF 100

int main(){
        FILE *fp = fopen("my_huge_file.txt","r");
        char str[BUF];
        int count=0;
        while( (fgets(str, BUF, fp)) != NULL ){
                for (int i = 0; i<BUF;i++){
                        if (str[i] == 'A')
                                count++;
                }
        }

        printf("We had %d \'A\'s\n",count);

}
```

Running this using `time ./a.out` prints:

> ```
> We had 420538682 'A's
>
> real  0m31.267s
> user  0m28.590s
> sys   0m2.531s
> ```

I then used `time tr -cd A < my_huge_file.txt | wc -c` and got back:

> ```
> 420538233
>
> real  0m13.611s
> user  0m10.688s
> sys   0m3.297s
> ```

I also used python's count method `time count.py`:

```
c = 0
with open("my_huge_file.txt", 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        c += line.count('A')


print(c)
```

> ```
> 420538233
>
> real  0m33.073s
> user  0m30.232s
> sys   0m2.650s
> ```

I am not sure how to investigate this discrepancy. tr and python's count are returning 420538233. The C function returns 420538682.

Comment: You are using `fgets` to read a line but not honoring the line boundaries when you count.  There is nothing line oriented about this problem.  Instead of `fgets`, use `fgetc`.  That simplifies the logic and makes the current error disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
        for (int i = 0; i<BUF;i++){
```

to

```
    for (int i = 0; i<BUF && str[i] ;i++){
```

See if you get a different output....

Comment: This worked! It gives `420538233` I assume there were unempty chars from previous for loops that were being added?

Comment: most likely; also, conventionally you should read into a LINE_MAX (from limits.h) buffer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to complicate your code with `fgets`. (The problem you have is that `fgets` reads a line and only fills a portion of your buffer, but you are counting everything in the buffer, including values that did not come from the input.)  Just read one character at a time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int c;
        int count=0;
        FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;
        if( fp == NULL ){
                perror(argv[1]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        while( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF ){
                if( c == 'A' ){
                        count += 1;
                }
        }

        printf("We had %d 'A's\n", count);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't fgets buffer the I/O and run faster?

Comment: Both `fgets` and `fgetc` buffer the io.  The same number of `read` system calls will (almost certainly) be made.  If you're worried about that, use `fread` instead.  But it's not likely to be a significant improvement.  You might try `getc` as well, but again the difference is not likely to be significant.